# Is there a function I can use when having min and max condition values in a data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that look like this:

```
ID     Product    Option       Value     Calculated_Charge
1       ODS       REBATE        500          2.2              
2       FBS       PAYAS        10000         44              
3       SSD       BUNDL         200          0.88               
4       WXR       BUNDL        70000         308
```

What I'm trying to do is identify Revenue leakage. If a customer transacts they are charged a withdrawal fee that is determined by the amount the customer has withdrawn. The calculated fee is:

```
calculated_charge= Value * 0.44%
```

But if the customer's charged amount is less than the min_fee_value = $5 then output the min_fee_value instead of the calculated_charge. If the customer's Charged amount is greater than the max_fee_value = $60 then output the max_fee_value instead of the calculated_charge.

This is how i want my output to look like:

```
ID     Product    Option       Value     Calculated_Charge
 1       ODS       REBATE        500          5                
 2       FBS       PAYAS        10000         44               
 3       SSD       BUNDL         200          5                
 4       WXR       BUNDL        70000        60
```

I tried using this code, but it only outputs the calculated_charge:

```
if (df['Product]== 'ODS' ) and (df['Option']=='REBATE'):
 calculation = Value * 0.44%
  if calculation > 60:
     return 60
  elif calculation < 5:
     return 5
else:
   return calculation
```

Comment: `df['Calculated_Charge'].clip(5, 60)`

Answer (score 0):

Same as suggested by user3483203. Putting her so that this can be closed (please ask user3483203 post his answer & accept it)

```
df['Calculated_Charge'] = (df['Value']*0.0044).clip(5, 60)
```